# user, oauth_token, expires is missing from Facebook signed_request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/using-login-with-games/

they claim the json object is

```
{
   "oauth_token": "{user-access-token}",
   "algorithm": "HMAC-SHA256",
   "expires": 1291840400,
   "issued_at": 1291836800,
   "user_id": "218471"
}
```

but i got this

```
{
   "algorithm": "HMAC-SHA256",
   "code": "xxxxxx",
   "issued_at": 1291836800,
   "user_id": "218471"
}
```

Remark:

my app is in sand box mode

Permission: email; user_about_me; user_birthday; user_interests; user_location; user_games_activity

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to be exchanging the code for a token?

Comment: how about if I dont want to make one more call for getting the token. I just want the signed request to have all the user info. How should I do?

Comment: same here, and after have done everything correctly from their API document, I also end up with this...

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever someone has already logged into your game with Facebook
>   Login, the signed request will contain an oauth_token property that
>   gives you a token to use to make API calls.

you should be handling the login using JavaScript SDK not by the POST date that is sent on launching the canvas app.

IF you are disparate to get some info before he logs in you should exchanging code for an access token

To get an access token, make an HTTP GET request to the following OAuth endpoint:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
  client_id={app-id}
  &redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
  &client_secret={app-secret}
  &code={code-parameter}
```

you use ajax with that to prevent page from refreshing .